# Suggestion for ripping workout: any good workout repositories on the web?

Tags: workout-routines, burn-fat

Wandering through the site and playing with tag search I've not found any link and/or table listing a good workout for mass building, strength growing or body ripping.

I am sorry if I've not used the search function properly, but I would be very grateful to you if you could suggest me a good workout with the following features:

- 3 training sessions per week
- each training session duration: about 1 hour (or less)
- 3 ~ 4 months keeping up this training before switching to a different workout
- main goal: making muscles very visible burning fat (focus on six pack is very appreciated, albeit I know that localized burning is just an illusion and that you have to burn fat all over your body)

Due to the fact that my request is likely to be too specific, it could be easily generalized asking what are the best workout repositories on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: List questions like this are very much off topic.

Comment: Isn't this site purpose supposed to be related to fitness and workout rotuines?

Comment: Yes. But like all StackExchange sites questions have to have an objectively singular best answer. List questions (like asking "what are the best workouts") are too broad and have too many answers to be useful. Reread the FAQ and about pages, and try and ask more targeted questions in future.

Answer (score 2):

There's no **one** specific type of routine for getting "ripped".  It's generally agreed in the bobybuilding circles that the formula for getting ripped is an increase in exercise volume with a corresponding decrease in calories.  Each part of this equation should be done **gradually**.  For example, remove 250 to 500 calories from your total caloric intake over a period of a few weeks.  Evaluate the results and continue the process.  On the exercise side of the equation, this may mean performing more reps, or, more sets with the goal to burn more calories.  Regardless of the approach, getting "ripped" should be a gradual process.  You need to give your body a chance to adapt to its new restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Starting Strength by Mark Rippetoe. Read it and follow the program exactly, adding assistance exercises such as curls only on the Friday.You will have to bulk so leave the abs on the sideline for a few months and just cut afterwards. You will get big doing this, trust me.

Comment: Is the subtitle "Basic Barbell Training"?

Comment: Yes that is the book, I would highly recommend it to anyone.